# RandomAccessFile on Android

Tags: android

I have a file on android phone which I would like to securely wipe it.

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4448994/1008256).
It mentions `This is especially true on mobile devices containing flash, which has wear-leveling to prolong its life and isn't guaranteed to overwrite the same block internally when you overwrite a block on the filesystem.`

So, if I would to use the code [on](https://stackoverflow.com/a/858553/1008256).Would it securely wiped on android phone ? Or when I use `RandomAccessFile` to write data to the file, it would be on a new block instead of the original block ?

Is it totally 100% impossible to get known of the exact block pointer on `android` ?

Or I have to recursively create a file, write with random data until the storage space hits the max. Then I try to edit the file I wish to delete. Which the flash will be force to use the original block while I rewrite the content and delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to read the documentation about the Objects and Methods used in the code you mentioned [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/858036/how-to-securely-delete-files-in-java/858553#858553) , nothing points that you write over the real Blocks used to save the file, and note the file can be written in Non-Sequential blocks, i think my friend told me about article discuss this issue, and they solved it using C++.