# How to shred a file from external storage beyond recovery, using java code?

Tags: java, android, file, shred

How to shred a file from external storage beyond recovery, using java code in android?

Comment: You take your sdcard and Hulk smash it? Just joking. Did you tried opening a file and filing it with random numbers and saving it. Do this several times and it must be gone :)

Comment: "beyond recovery", maybe not... But you can open it, write random stuff into it, close it and then delete it.

Comment: Does this help? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/858036/how-to-securely-delete-files-in-java)